# Parsing JSON file using Python and Yahooquery

Tags: python, json, anaconda, yahoo-finance

I am trying to follow the steps in this article:
[Link Here](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/access-michael-burrys-portfolio-with-just-a-few-lines-of-code-b0763a771b5c)

I am using Jupyter in Anaconda.
I downloaded the json file from EDGAR and placed the file in the user folder where the jupyter file is held. When I run the first script, it does not seem to generate the 13F list as shown in the article. What am I doing wrong here?

The next step posed another issue, when I paste the script and run that, I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" stating that no module named 'yahooquery' exists... what does that mean?

Thank you for any help offered.

In case the article is not allowed, here is the first script that doesn't seem to generate the list:

```js
import json 
import pandas as pd

company_numer = "0001649339"

with open('CIK'+company_numer+'.json') as f:
    list_filings_json = json.load(f)
    
filings = pd.DataFrame()
filings["form"] = list_filings_json['filings']['recent']['form']
filings["accessionNumber"] = list_filings_json['filings']['recent']['accessionNumber']
filings["accessionNumber"] = filings["accessionNumber"].str.replace('-', '')
filings["filingDate"] = list_filings_json['filings']['recent']['filingDate']
filings["reportDate"] = list_filings_json['filings']['recent']['reportDate']
filings = filings[filings["form"]=="13F-HR"]
```

The second script that gives the ModuleNotFoundError is quite long so I will only show the start of it:

```js
import requests  
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 
import yahooquery as yq
import time

def parse_XML(xml_file): 
    
    xtree = et.parse(xml_file)
    xroot = xtree.getroot()
    rows = []
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Have you installed `yahooquery` in the kernel that's running your notebook?

Comment: Hi crcvd - I have not installed it. I thought anaconda came with these packages. This would not solve the first issue that I have though. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Can I get anyone to take a look at the first problem for me?